# Why does restoring an iPhone backup not result in all apps being updated?

Tags: iphone, ios, backup, restore

After apple made it impossible to save and restore apps to and from iTunes and instead started relying solely on AppStore redownloads to restore apps, combined with the fact that I can't manually install earlier versions of apps on the AppStore even if I wanted to, I'm wondering why I get the exact same version of the app back after restoring from a backup? I.e. I have the same app updates waiting for me in the AppStore after a backup restore, following an erase of all contents and settings — which in my case was also followed by a restore in iTunes to a new version of iOS.

As someone who updates apps individually and manually I think it's perfect since some of my apps will become useless if updated, but I didn't expect it.

iOS 10.3.1 -> 10.3.3

Comment: What do you do exactly for "factory reset"? - There is "reset all settings", and "Erase all content and settings". Doing the first would leave all apps on your phone. Restoring from backup also does not overwrite your apps, backup only generally saves data and settings, not actual apps. iOS backup does not work like a TimeMachine or a full disk backup like on desktop. Notice that on your Mac, a full iOS backup is not 16GB for a full 16GB iPhone.

Comment: @ChrisPaveglio Erase all contents and settings. In my case followed by a reset from iTunes to a newer version of iOS.